# Data retrieval works within a controller but not when I use a service - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am implementing some functionality to retrieve a list of employees from database to display within my AngularJS application. I created a controller that current works as displayed below:

```
 $scope.getEmployee = function () {
        $http.get("EmpWebService.asmx/GetEmp")
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.employees = response.data;
        });
    }
```

I tried to move this logic to be used within a service but the data is returning `undefined`. It's strange because this was working fine few days ago but suddenly it does not appear to be working. Here is the code:

Controller

```
$scope.getEmployee2 = function () {
        $scope.employees = fetchEmpService.fetchEmp();
    }
```

Service.js

```
fetchEmp: function () {
            debugger;
            return $http.get("EmpWebService.asmx/GetEmp")
                .then(function (response) {
                    return response.data;

                });
        }
```

Comment: Have you injected `$http` to your service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above code will not work because fetchEmp will return a promise so $scope.employees is a promise not the employee list, try to do this,

```
$scope.getEmployee2 = function () {
    fetchEmpService.fetchEmp().then(function (employeeList){
        $scope.employees = employeeList;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, thats my solution

Answer (score 1):

fetchEmpService.fetchEmp() returns a promise. You can access the employees object from this service in it success callback.

```
$scope.getEmployee2 = function () {
   fetchEmpService.fetchEmp()
    .then(function(emp){
        $scope.employees = emp;
    });
}
```